# Configurar o visual studio 2010 para abrir paginas .aspx sempre com o source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Como configurar o **visual studio 2010** para abrir paginas .aspx sempre com o source?

Comment: Você quer que abra o .vb ou o source do aspx (html) ?

Comment: Quero que ao clicar duas vezes no arquivo .aspx ele já abra o source que contém ó código html, manja?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Basta configurar no visual studio.

Vá em TOOLS > OPTIONS e faça igual na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s153/visual-studio-html-view.htm